# Babel, Webpack and Mobx: TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined

Tags: webpack, babeljs, eslint, mobx, mobx-react

In the process of integrating ESLint to a MobX with decorators React project, I run into the problem of the stores being undefined.

I have read a lot of the posts regarding how to use decorators with mobx and there's a definite, reported way to make it work, but at the same time there's a sentiment in the air to just not use them and instead use the wrapper functions the decorators replace. I would not like to lose the readability and ease of use in way of a solution, but at this moment I'm not sure what else I can try to have this working.

At this moment I have two separate git branches in my project and can provide examples of the working build with decorators, as mentioned above the problem arises when adding linting tools

Code samples in question below:

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import LazyRoute from 'lazy-route';
import styles from './styles/app.css';

@withRouter
@inject('store')
@observer
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.store = this.props.store; 
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //here's where the error is triggered, authenticate is a function in the store but it throws undefined
    this.store.appState.authenticate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`container-fluid ${styles.wrapper}`}>
        <Route exact path="/" render={props => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Home')} />} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" render={props => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Profile')} />} />
        <Route exact path="/balance" render={props => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Balance')} />} />
        <Route render={props => <LazyRoute {...props} component={import('./Home')} />} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{   "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"],   "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"] }
```

dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel": "^6.5.2",
"babel-core": "^6.18.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
"babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.16.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
"css-loader": "^0.25.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
"image-webpack-loader": "^2.0.0",
"node-sass": "^3.10.1",
"postcss-loader": "^0.13.0",
"react-hot-loader": "next",
"resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^2.4.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0 || ^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
    "faker": "^3.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lazy-route": "^1.0.7",
    "mobx": "^2.5.2",
    "mobx-react": "4.0.0",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.6",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "latest",
    "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-loader": "^2.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "latest",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^0.0.8",
    "rfx-core": "^1.5.3",
    "transform-runtime": "^0.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0"
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', 'babel-polyfill', 'whatwg-fetch', './src/index.jsx'],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 8000,
    host: 'localhost',
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'app.[hash].js',
  },
  devtool: 'eval',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$|jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss|css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          'postcss-loader',
          'resolve-url-loader',
          'sass-loader?sourceMap',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              progressive: true,
              optimizationLevel: 7,
              interlaced: false,
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ hash: false, template: './index.hbs' }),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /nb/),
  ],
};
```

Full console error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined
at App.componentDidMount (webpack:///./src/components/App.jsx?:54:26)
at App.target.(anonymous function) (webpack:///./~/mobx-react/index.js?:262:13)
at eval (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:264:25)
at measureLifeCyclePerf (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:75:12)
at eval (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js?:263:11)
at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/CallbackQueue.js?:76:22)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js?:80:26)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js?:209:25)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/Transaction.js?:156:16)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (webpack:///./~/react-dom/lib/ReactMount.js?:126:15)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced with that problem. That may help you:

1) Create a file in a root of project `jsconfig.json` containing following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

2) You've already install `"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"`, but maybe didn't use it. Try add `'transform-class-properties'` to `.babelrc` in plugins section right after `'transform-decorators-legacy'`, in my case it helped me. Your plugins in `.babelrc` should looks like:

```
plugins: [
       'transform-decorators-legacy',
       'transform-class-properties',
 ]
```

Comment: I tried your approach and it unfortunately didn't solve the issue. It's also worth pointing out that it is **jsconfig.json**, not **jsconfig.js**

Comment: still the same error? Yeah, right .json, sorry, i'll edit my typo.

Comment: If you want, you can check my working to-do example with mobx and decorators, compare some things. Here the link https://github.com/spiderpoul/react-to-do Or if you have this project on the github you can share it, i'll can check it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I did check your project and tried to see if I could replicate your results, with no luck. I will come back later and add more info when I have the time so this is helpful for someone else at least